# Uso HTTPS e quero somente uma URL com HTTP com Nginx

Tags: http, nginx, https

Tenho um site configurado em um servidor Nginx para forçar HTTPS para todo o site, mas preciso que somente uma URL seja em HTTP somente mantendo o restante do site em HTTPS.

A URL é exatamente esta:

> https://site.meudominio.com.br/index.php?route=primeiro/segundo/terceiro/funcao

Quero que ela seja forçada a ficar em HTTP somente tipo assim e mantenha:

> http://site.meudominio.com.br/index.php?route=primeiro/segundo/terceiro/funcao

Meu arquivo de configuração é assim:

```
server {

    listen      80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name site.meudominio.com.br;
    return 301 https://site.meudominio.com.br$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen      443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name site.meudominio.com.br;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/privkey.pem;

    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /var/www/meudominio.com.br/site;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
         try_files $uri @meudominio;
    }

    location @meudominio {
      rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você disse "uma URL", qual URL exatamente, ou se refere um dominio em HTTP e os demais HTTPS?

Comment: Somente uma URL no mesmo dominio, a url esta descrita ai na questão, conto com sua ajuda ;)!